# Change the color of fill of path in css for specific path

Tags: css, angular, charts, kendo-ui, styles

I'm using Kendo pie chart for Angular
the chart has a white background, which is my problem, I found from inspect at real time that there is SVG has 2 paths.

[image]

when I'm using in css the following style to get the background transparent

```
:host::ng-deep  path {
  fill: transparent;
}
```

I can't see even the chart. for example if I change the fill to yellow, the background and the whole chart is yellow.
[image]

which is supposed to be like this

[image]

My target is to change the background from default attribute style which is

```
path[Attributes Style] {
    d: path("M 0 0 L 60 0 L 60 60 L 0 60 Z");
    stroke: none;
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

**to transparent only for the first path**

Comment: Can you not just set the background property of the ChartArea?  https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/ChartArea/#toc-background

Comment: this is areaChart. My example is PieChart

Comment: ChartArea applies to all chart types